# RabbitMQ configuring dynamic shovel error - 'component shovel not found'

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I'm trying to configure a dynamic shovel on RabbitMQ 3.2.3 after installing the Shovel plugin. However, when I run the following command:

```
rabbitmqctl set_parameter shovel test-shovel '{"src-uri": "amqp://", "src-queue": "queueName", "dest-uri": "amqp://user:password@host", "dest-queue": "queueName"}'
```

...I get this error message:

```
Error: Validation failed

component shovel not found
```

The plugin appears to be installed correctly. If I run:

```
rabbitmq-plugins list
```

...I get:

```
[e] amqp_client                       3.2.3
[ ] cowboy                            0.5.0-rmq3.2.3-git4b93c2d
[ ] eldap                             3.2.3-gite309de4
[e] mochiweb                          2.7.0-rmq3.2.3-git680dba8
[ ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_federation               3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc                  3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel          3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel_examples 3.2.3
[E] rabbitmq_management               3.2.3
[e] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.2.3
[E] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.2.3
[E] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.2.3
[e] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.2.3
[ ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.2.3
[ ] rfc4627_jsonrpc                   3.2.3-git5e67120
[ ] sockjs                            0.3.4-rmq3.2.3-git3132eb9
[e] webmachine                        1.10.3-rmq3.2.3-gite9359c7
```

Also, if I run:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_shovel_status:status().'
```

...I get:

```
[]
...done.
```

Any ideas?! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you restart RMQ? after installed shovel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like dynamic shovels were added in 3.3.0, doh! We're still on 3.2.3.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.3.0.txt

Comment: That is not really so. In my case there is RabbitMQ 3.3.5, shovel plugin enabled and shovels created statically (via config file) work well. Attept to define dinamic shovel end with error: `Error: Validation failed component shovel not found`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 
Typically this behavior is when you install a plug-in and you don't restart RabbitMQ server.

Restart RMQ is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur due to a race condition in RMQ versions prior to `3.8.6`. Until `3.8.6`, loading static definitions could happen before plugins were activated, causing this validation error. For more information, see GitHub issue [rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server#2384](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2384).